# menu on nexus 7 that does not have menu button

Tags: android, menu, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-7, android-optionsmenu

I am working on `android` app. I am testing and running my app on Nexus 7. I have created a menu. But its NOT appearing on Nexux 7 device. The OS codename on my device is KitKat.

I found this resource https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/F3aU3fThMMk

That says Nexus 7 does not have menu button. But if there is no button, it should appear on tablet in the start of the app.

The function `onCreateOptionsMenu` is Not getting called when app runs. I assume that there must be a menu button that triggers `onCreateOptionsMenu` function.

Please let me know what I need to do to make it appear(menu) on Nexus 7 device

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

My activity class was extended from `FragmentActivity`.

But when I used `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` it solved my problem and now my toolbar plus menu appearing as they should.

But I still could not figure out why there hasn't been any response to my question so far.

Even though I answered my own question without any response yet. I will NOT accept my own answer and that gives room to more further explanation from someone from `android` community on SO.